# Joomla Registration form Fields Ordering

Tags: joomla

How do I order the fields on my joomla registration form?

As you can see, the captcha must be at the bottom:
http://www.celinasoft.com/index.php/component/users/?view=registration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you will need to create your Registration view template override (to keep it Joomla update proof). To do so, create folder `/templates/YOUT_TEMPLATE/html/com_users/registration` and copy `/components/com_users/views/registration/tmpl/default.php` file there.

Then you will need to modify the code itself, open `/templates/YOUT_TEMPLATE/html/com_users/registration/default.php` file, you will see, that by default Joomla takes ALL fields from `registration.xml` file and just loops them through foreach cycle, this code:

```
<?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldsets() as $fieldset): ?>
...
...
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You need to replace this cycle by your manual fields output like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('email'); ?></div>
  <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('email'); ?></div>
</div>
...
...
```

And output all desired registration fields like that, in order you prefer. **Warning:** don't forget that almost all of that fields are required for registration and cannot be missed.

You can find all field names in XML file `components/com_users/models/forms/registration.xml`

Please note that this is only sample code, to understand the logics. It haven't been tested live. So if errors occur - please let me know and we'll fix it :)

If anyone have a better/easier solution - I'd be happy to hear it.